# Sql error while creating tables - Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, ddl, sqldatatypes, ibexpert

I have simple sql code for `create table` and then `add constraint` to it. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bills (
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    code        VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    dateOfGeneration   DATE NOT NULL,
    job_id     INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE bills ADD CONSTRAINT bills_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id,job_id );
```

I am using IBExpert - client for Firebird. When I execute this code I get 2 errors:

**First error**: - in  *code        VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL*

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 29.
(.
```

**Second error**: - in code *ALTER TABLE ...*

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 8, column 1.
ALTER.
```

The first one I think is because i am using `varchar2` instead of `varchar`. What about second error? How to fix this?

Comment: VARCHAR2? Is that data type really supported by Firebord?

Comment: i thought like that, but it seems it is not. varchar is working. what about alter table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no `VARCHAR2` type in Firebird - https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-chartypes.html
2. If you want to run two commands - you have to run TWO commands. You try to run two commands in one, but that is not a way to do it. You have to split them and run one after another. Or you have to wrap them into one `EXECUTE BLOCK` command.
3. Also `IBExpert` has a separate window of `Script Executive` for multiple commands running. It is not `SQL Editor` which is designed to execute ONE command, it is a separate window in another menu - https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.ScriptExecutive

Table creation command is described here: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html

Basically what you trying to do looks like this, if to do it in one command:

```
CREATE TABLE bills (
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    code        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    dateOfGeneration   DATE NOT NULL,
    job_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id,job_id )
)
```

or if you insist on naming then perhaps

```
CREATE TABLE bills (
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    code        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    dateOfGeneration   DATE NOT NULL,
    job_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT bills_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id,job_id )
)
```